# How to make pushbutton's icon in PyQt5 to change it's color dependent on if the button is pressed

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to make pushbutton's icon in PyQt5 to change it's color dependent on if the button is pressed

I tried this:

```
    self.example_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.example_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 650, 70, 70))
    self.example_button.setObjectName("Example")
    icon = QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QPixmap('./symbols/Example.png'), QIcon.Normal)
    icon.addPixmap(QPixmap('./symbols/Example.png'), QIcon.Disabled)
    self.read_style("circular_push_button.css", self.example_button)
    self.example_button.setIcon(icon)
    size = QSize(62, 62)
    self.example_button.setIconSize(size)
```

but nothing happened when I press the button. How can I do it the right way?

Comment: why it didn't work? did you have a error? than please show the error

Comment: it shows no error but nothing happened when I presse the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is following:

```
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap('./symbols/Example.png'), QIcon.Normal)
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap('./symbols/Example.png'), QIcon.Disabled)
```

You add same icon for both states, change one of them and it should work.

I am not fully sure how qt works now, didn't work with it few years, but maybe you need to add listener for mouse events as well, an example can be found [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551263/how-to-change-icon-while-mouse-is-clicking-in-pyqt5)